# How to set picker's selected item in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a picker with that gets the customer outlet. I want to update the what I saved from my database.

Here is my app logic:
1. The user will select a customer outlet
2. The user will save the selected outlet
3. The user will have an option to update what the user selected
4. Upon loading of the page the customer outlet on the picker will be loaded and the what the user saved on will be the item.

How can I achieve this?

Here are my codes:

Here is how I load all of outlet:

```
var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
var conn = db.GetConnection();

var getCode = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT * FROM tblContacts LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCustomerMember ON tblCustomerMember.CustomerID = tblContacts.ContactID WHERE CustomerID = ? AND tblCustomerMember.Deleted !='1'", lblCustomer.Text);
var resultCount = getCode.Result.Count;
if (resultCount > 0)
{
   var result = getCode.Result;
   pckOutlet.ItemsSource = result;
}
else
{
    pckOutlet.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

And here is my XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="pckOutlet" Focused="PckOutlet_Focused" SelectedIndexChanged="PckOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}" StyleClass="formcontrol" IsEnabled="False">
     <Picker.FontFamily>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
               <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Regular.ttf#SFProDisplay-Regular"/>
              </OnPlatform>
      </Picker.FontFamily>
</Picker>
```

Comment: So what you want is on the basis of your first picker the customer outlet, you want the other pickers to change data?

Comment: I just want to set the selected data of the picker will be the one the user saved

Comment: What do you mean by the one that user saved?

Comment: The user is saving the id of the outlet when the id match the id of the list of the outlet that should be the selected item

Comment: You are trying to have a Default selected item may be?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes I am, so that the can update it if they want

Comment: Just bind it to the selected property in that case !

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Sure give me some time

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SelectedItem property to the previously selected item.

```
if (resultCount > 0)
{
   var result = getCode.Result;
   pckOutlet.ItemsSource = result;
   pckOutlet.SelectedItem = result.First(outlet => outlet.Id == *PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_ID*)
}
```

You may need to store the previously selected ID somewhere where it can survive app resets. Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage or Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences can be used for this and is fairly straight forward to use.